# Calling instance method in iphone to set value causing crash by printing "(lldb)" in iOS Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, lldb

I am calling by button click in class **SFAViewController**

```
-(IBAction)uploadselector:(id)sender  // Notes and Attachments
{
    SFAUploadController *uploadcontroller = [[SFAUploadController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SFAUploadController" bundle:nil];
    //[SFAUploadController setRecordId:selectedrecordid];
    [self.view addSubview:uploadcontroller.view];
    [uploadcontroller setRecordId:selectedrecordid];
    NSLog(@"Okay uploading.. with record id %@",selectedrecordid);

}
```

which calls instance method in class **SFAUploadController** :-

```
-(void)setRecordId:(NSString *)value  // called by SFAViewController.m 
{
    self.receivedrecordid = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Empty"];
    NSLog(@"Record value set");
    //receivedrecordid = value;
}

-(IBAction)selectfile:(id)sender // called when a button clicked in SFAUploadController class
{
    NSLog(@"Record in second class: %@",self.receivedrecordid); // causing program crash saying "(lldb)"
}
```

Please explain me why this happening? I am not so familiar with passing values reference from one class to another class in iphone.

Thanks.

Comment: you might be calling `selectfile` before `receivedrecordid` gets value? it can be good idea to check for nil before printing, it will avoid the crash

Comment: well I have tried printing in `-(void)setRecordId:(NSString *)value ` method string is set to "Empty" literal but when clicked on `selectfile` event, it causes crash. `selectfile` is being called in last.

Comment: There is nothing more than "lldb". it pointing to line `NSLog(@"Record in second class: %@",self.receivedrecordid);` saying BAD EXC code 2.

Comment: What if you type `bt` in the debugger console?

Comment: could it be that _self.receivedrecordid_ isn't allocated? The setRecordId: message will send to the object by clicking on a button and execute the _uploadselector:_ action. How did you make sure that the _selectfile:_ action will execute after execute _uploadselector:_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be clicking on `selectfile` before `receivedrecordid` gets value? it can be good idea to check for nil before printing, it will avoid the crash, how you declare your receivedrecordid? you could make this property `strong` if you are using ARC otherwise `retain`, you should also check that you are connecting the IBAction for method `selectfile` properly for event touch up inside.
From symptoms it looks like you are using an object which is not available or released/unallocated already. you should make sure all your objects and instances are being used in a proper way.

it is always good idea to use the viewController as property in other class so that it can be retained as long as corresponding class is alive.

in your particular case, as you are setting the value to the string only nothing big, then you could do that directly without using explicit method

```
uploadController.receivedRecordId=@"stirng you want to assign";
```

Comment: Yes I have connected the IBAction for method `selectfile` that is causing crash and I have already set the property as `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *receivedrecordid;` There may some mistake in passing value from one class to another. I am not sure.

Comment: post the stack trace as @trojanfoe said, what error you get on the console? it could be easier to identify the problem that way

Comment: why not you set value to     `self.receivedrecordid = @"Empty";` or `self.receivedrecordid=value;`?

Comment: `libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x158508c:  movl   8(%esp), %ecx
0x1585090:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x1585094:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x1585096:  je     0x015850e8               ; objc_msgSend + 92
0x1585098:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x158509a:  pushl  %edi
0x158509b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi
0x158509e:  pushl  %esi
0x158509f:  movl   (%edi), %esi
0x15850a1:  movl   %ecx, %edx
0x15850a3:  shrl   $2, %edx
0x15850a6:  andl   %esi, %edx
0x15850a8:  movl   8(%edi,%edx,4), %eax
0x15850ac:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x15850ae:  je     0x015850b9               ; objc_msgSend + 45
0x15850b0:  cmpl   (%eax), %ecx
`

Comment: I set `self.receivedrecordid = @"Empty";` because in want to sure if this problem is not related to nil/null value

Comment: @Ashwin first enable the zombies in your project in order to get the readable message on console for the problem, can you set the zombies to your project? and post this stack trace in your question.it could be also that you are trying to release something which has been released already? are you releasing some objects?

Comment: `0x1347dc0:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1347dc3:  calll  0x01423bc6               ; sel_getName
0x1347dc8:  movl   %edi, 16(%esp)
0x1347dcc:  movl   %eax, 12(%esp)
0x1347dd0:  addl   $10, %esi
0x1347dd3:  movl   %esi, 8(%esp)
0x1347dd7:  leal   1238746(%ebx), %eax
0x1347ddd:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1347de1:  movl   $3, (%esp)
0x1347de8:  calll  0x01392aa0               ; CFLog
0x1347ded:  int3   
0x1347dee:  calll  0x01423884               ; getpid //Here is Thread 1 EXC_Breakpoint
0x1347df3:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1347df6:  movl   $9, 4(%esp)
0x1347dfe:  calll  0x014238d8               ; kill`

Comment: No, I am using ARC. Not realeasing any object. I have enabled zombies and post the stack trace above.

Comment: go to your Xcode->Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme-> in Diagnostics tab, within memory management section, enable zombies  objects

Comment: *** -[SFAUploadController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6c7d090
(lldb)  // I am seeing this on console.

Comment: you are sending message to deallocated instance, you should make sure that you are not releasing any object, you should show more code where you performing the selector?

Comment: where is [SFAUploadController performSelector:withObject:withObject:] in your code? you need to show that, you are doing something wrong there i assume

Comment: I don,t have ` [SFAUploadController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]` anywhere in my code.

Comment: I used nothing more than this: `SFAUploadController *uploadcontroller = [[SFAUploadController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SFAUploadController" bundle:nil];
    //[SFAUploadController setRecordId:selectedrecordid];
    [self.view addSubview:uploadcontroller.view];
    [uploadcontroller setRecordId:selectedrecordid];
    NSLog(@"Okay uploading.. with record id %@",selectedrecordid);`

Comment: alright, make SFAUploadController also property to the SFAViewController class, it migh solve your problem i think

Comment: do you mean `@property (strong, nonatomic) SFAUploadController *somePointerName`

Comment: But I need to use it as `SFAUploadController *uploadcontroller = [[SFAUploadController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SFAUploadController" bundle:nil];` by setting it property, I have to use its pointerName instead. I have used previously it is same as current issue.

Comment: it is same as you declare instance in your method, but you use it as a global property within the class, so it will be available as long as class lives

Comment: can't make property to SFAUploadController Error: Unknown Type name.

Comment: first declare `@class SFAUploadController;` in your .h file and then make property from it

Comment: Thanks, This approach worked perfectly. Can you please help me regarding passing value from one class to another class in iOS. Or I can say using multiple classes in iOS project. Any help will be good for me. Thanks again.

Comment: if you need some data or method which is shared/called by multiple classes then it can be good idea to create a singelton class and declare those methods there, secondly in your case as you are only setting the string, then you might not need any string, just use `uploadController.receivedRecordId=@"string you want to assign";`

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to create setter method for setting value to your `receivedrecordid` variable in `SFAUploadController` class.

Instead of creating setter method you can create `@property` for setting value to `receivedrecordid` like following:

`SFAUploadController.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSting *receivedrecordid;
```

And in `SFAUploadController.m` synthesize it like

```
@synthesize receivedrecordid;
```

Now you can directly use it like:

```
-(IBAction)uploadselector:(id)sender  // Notes and Attachments
{
    SFAUploadController *uploadcontroller = [[SFAUploadController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SFAUploadController" bundle:nil];
    [uploadcontroller setSelectedrecordid:@"recordId"];
    [self.view addSubview:uploadcontroller.view];
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for this approach. But i used it like this: `uploadcontroller.receivedrecordid = selectedrecodid;`